# How do I get a Fusion 3D Model into Unreal

Tags: autodesk, fbx, unreal-engine4

So I am working on a 3D model for days in Fusion 360 and now I need to get it into Unreal Engine.  The problem is that Fusion 360 supports CAD formats and Unreal Engine only supports .FBX file formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use Blender to Import the Fusion 360 STL file format and then export from Blender as an .FBX.  (GO Blender TEAM !!!)

Answer (score 1):

You can also export directly to FBX from A360.

- Go to your file in A360
- Click the toolbox icon
- Export and select FBX
- Give the server some time to do the file conversion

You can then download the file.